# How to debug 500.0 / 0x00000000 error on System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

I'm getting this strange error which I am unable to figure out. Running on Windows 8.1, IIS 8.5. The site runs fine on Microsoft Azure so it must be a local configuration issue. I get the same errors in IIS Express as I do with IIS.

The problem has been around for a few days and it's driving me mental. I can't even test simple CSS/Content changes (which is what I am trying to do) without pushing them up to Azure each time to check.

**ERROR:**

```
Module          global.asax
Notification    EndRequest
Handler         System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
Error Code      0x00000000
Requested URL   https://localhost:443/
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User      Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles
```

Here is the [trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdQMp.png) for the section just before the warning.

**THINGS I'VE TRIED**

- Reinstall IIS, .NET 4.5, Visual Studio
- Checked permissions: IIS_IUSRS has access to the folder and files
- Installed a basic MVC 5 demo app. Runs perfectly under the website & app-pool in question.
- Put a basic aspx hello world page in the root of my website directory. It loads when in the Default web site, but when under the website in question I get a "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" error.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this same error message and I couldn't get any tracing or logging to happen. After days of research I realized it was an unhandled exception in Global.asax.cs. I would recommend auditing your Global.asax code to see if there is any opportunity for exceptions to happen.

Regardless, you might want to follow the best practice to handle such Application-level errors  to output the last error message to a custom page:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/24395wz3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It could also be a runtime compilation error occurring in view trying to be loaded

Answer (score 2):

- comment out all you code inside Global.asax.cs `Application_Error` method

Answer (score 1):

I found the detailed error on Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application

Turns out my AppPool user didn't had access to the database

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that your application pool is a bit misconfigured. Try to set proper version of .Net framework [as proposed in MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at that and it all seems correct. .NET CLR Version v4.0.x, pipeline is set to integrated.

Comment: Try to run following commands:

`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i` and
`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue ended up being when the `View` of the page I was browsing hit a `Property` in the `ViewModel` that loaded some additional stuff... and that stuff hit some bad data... and because it was the `View` that hit that `Property`, instead of showing the actual error, it instead showed the generic 500 error... to fix, I just added this statement at the top of the `View`:

```
@{ return; }
```

And when the error went away, I kept moving the above statement lower and lower until I found which line caused the error.