# HTTP Error 500.0 - System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler 0x00000000 - can't launch app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC app on VS2015. I have reinstalled asp.net via command line statement

[image: Error 1]

[image: App running user]

[image: Additional log]
[image: Call Stack]

Trying to add features, i ran into errors and
[followed suggestion as per](https://superuser.com/questions/462078/not-all-features-were-successfully-changed-when-trying-to-add-application-deve) but that did not solve the issue. as well as [article on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892827/how-to-debug-500-0-0x00000000-error-on-system-web-mvc-mvchandler)

I have .bet 4.7 installed but can't enable its features using `Add windows features`

Current version used in package.config

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" allowedVersions="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Your error states: `.NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.`

Comment: Yes, but how do i install it. Windows features has this option checked.